# Sending data Curl/Json in Python

Tags: python, dashing

I`m trying to make those 2  requests in python:

Request 1:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth_token": "auth1", "widget":   "id1", "title": "Something1",  "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }'   serverip
```

Request 2:

```
 vsphere_dict = {}
 vsphere_dict['server_name'] = "servername"
 vsphere_dict['api_version'] = apiVersion
 vsphere_dict['guest_count'] = guestCount
 vsphere_dict['guest_on']    = guestOnLen
 vsphere_dict['guest_off']   = guestOffLen

 #Convert output to Json to be sent
 data = json.dumps(vsphere_dict)

 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d 'data' serverip
```

Neither of them seems to work. Is there any way I can send them in Python?

Update:

The part that I cannot handle is the pass auth and widget. I have tried the following without success:

```
import urllib2
import urllib

vsphere_dict = dict(
    server_name="servername",
    api_version="apiVersion",
    guest_count="guestCount",
    guest_on="guestOnLen",
    guest_off="guestOffLen",
)

url = "http://ip:port"

auth = "authid89"
widget = "widgetid1"

# create request object, set url and post data
req = urllib2.Request(auth,url, data=urllib.urlencode(vsphere_dict))
# set header
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
# send request
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)**
```

Resulting in "urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error"

Any ideas how I can pass the auth and widget correctly?

UPDATE:

To see what is different I have started a nc server locally. Here are the results:

Correct curl request using this code:

```
 curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{ "auth_token": "auth", "widget": "widgetid", "title": "Something", "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }' http://localhost:8123
```

sends this **which does work:**

```
 POST / HTTP/1.1
 User-Agent: curl/7.21.0 (i386-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.0 NSS/3.12.10.0 zlib/1.2.5  libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.2.4
 Host: localhst:8123
 Accept: */*
 Content-Type: application/json
 Content-Length: 165

 { "auth_token": "token", "widget": "widgetid", "title": "Something", "text": "Some text", "moreinfo": "Subtitle" }
```

And request using this code

```
  import requests
  import simplejson as json

  url = "http://localhost:8123"
  data = {'auth_token': 'auth1', 'widget': 'id1', 'title': 'Something1', 'text': 'Some   text', 'moreinfo': 'Subtitle'}
  headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
  r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

sends this which **does not work:**

```
 POST / HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhst:8123
 Content-Length: 108
 Content-type: application/json
 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
 Accept: */*
 User-Agent: python-requests/2.0.1 CPython/2.7.0 Linux/2.6.35.14-106.fc14.i686

 {"text": "Some text", "auth_token": "auth1", "moreinfo": "Subtitle", "widget": "id1",  "title": "Something1"}
```

Comment: Did you use subprocess module?

Answer (score 8):

[Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) provides you with the simplest and yet (very) powerful way to deal with HTTP requests in Python.

Maybe try something like this:

```
import requests
import simplejson as json

url = "http://ip:port"
data = {'auth_token': 'auth1', 'widget': 'id1', 'title': 'Something1', 'text': 'Some text', 'moreinfo': 'Subtitle'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
```

If the API requests authentication:

```
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

See [Requests auth] for details.

Comment: That seems perfect yet does not solve the problem. I am getting:>>> r.reason
'Unauthorized'

Comment: Maybe the API your are posting to is requesting Authentication? If so, see [authentication](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/), and don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: BasicAuth example added to the answer.

Comment: Not working I`m still getting 401!!. Here is are some examples on auth.http://shopify.github.io/dashing/#overview

Comment: Looks like you need to pass your auth token in the request body and not use standard Auth header (which is weird). Drop the auth= part in the request and make sure your auth_token is legit. Please accept the answer as you're now dealing with a different issue than 'sending data with python'.

Comment: It actually still is sending data wirh python.  I have done some tests updating the main question.

Answer (score 2):

Well sure, using Python-Requests which is a Python library for sending requests like Curl. You can take a look at the [Complicated Post Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) section.

Or, if you'd like to use curl inside of Python, you can use [pyCurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Auth and Widget are the fiels I am using to authenticate to the server. I need to send them as first 2 parameters and send the data later. Still no luck

Answer (score 2):

In the example from the Dashing website, they use:

```
curl -d '{ "auth_token": "YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN", "current": 100 }' http://localhost:3030/widgets/karma
```

From the cURL man page, maybe you need to post it as form-urlencoded?

-d, --data

(HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server, in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the data to the server using the content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form.

-d, --data is the same as --data-ascii. To post data purely binary, you should instead use the --data-binary option. To URL-encode the value of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.

If any of these options is used more than once on the same command line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.

If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data from stdin. Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named 'foobar' would thus be done with --data @foobar. When --data is told to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be stripped out.

You might also want to try python-requests http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

**Update: I got it to work**

```
import requests
import json

payload = {'auth_token': 'YOUR_AUTH_TOKEN', 'title': "pythontest"}
r = requests.post("http://localhost:3030/widgets/welcome", data=json.dumps(payload))

print r.text
```

You need to post the json like a form.

Answer (score 1):

why not use urllib2?

```
import urllib2
import urllib

vsphere_dict = dict(
    server_name="servername",
    api_version=apiVersion,
    guest_count=guestCount,
    guest_on=guestOnLen,
    guest_off=guestOffLen,
)
# create request object, set url and post data
req = urllib2.Request(some_url, data=urllib.urlencode(vsphere_dict))
# set header
req.add_header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
# send request
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

UPD:

sorry, by i not understand that is `auth` and `widget`. Maybe this is also POST data?
HTTP Error 500 - can mean that server received not all POST parameters.